# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: html, jakarta-ee, arraylist, datatable, javabeans

I'm learning JavaEE, and looking for some help. I'm trying to get all record from a Derby DB table to display on a xhtml page (dataTable). I received this error "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList".

1. Can someone explain the error and how I need to fix it?
2. How do I trigger the data table to be shown only when the "Print" button is clicked?
   Thanks in advance

My named query:

> NamedQueries({
>       @NamedQuery(name="getAllItemActivities", query="select c from LibraryItemActivity c")
>   })

My bean manager:

> private ArrayList activities;
>
> public ArrayList getActivities() {
>
> ```
>   return control.getActivites();
> ```
>
> }

My control bean:

> public ArrayList getActivites() {
>
> ```
>   ArrayList<LibraryItemActivity> temp = (ArrayList<LibraryItemActivity>) em.createNamedQuery("getAllItemActivities").getResultList();
>
>   return temp;
> ```
>
> }

My html data table:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value = "Print"></h:commandButton>
    <h:dataTable value = "#{libraryBeanManager.activities}" var = "a">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Book Title:</f:facet>
            #{a.libraryitemtitle}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Author:</f:facet>
            #{a.patron}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Publisher:</f:facet>
            #{a.activitytype}
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>  
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[javax.persistence.Query.getResultList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList--) returns a [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), not an ArrayList.

Change your ArrayList declarations to java.util.List.